# Получить список категорий

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть список категорий с многоуровневыми подкатегориями.
Как мне вывести только те категории/подкатегории, у которых вложенные подкатегории не имеют ничего общего с указанным родителем?

Например, есть категории с `id=1,2` и `parent_id = null` и подкатегории с `id=3,4,5,6`, у которых общий `parent_id=1`, и подкатегория с `id=9`, у которой `parent_id=4`. В итоге, если указать `id=1`, то категории с `id=3,4,5,6,9` не должны отобразиться, т.к. они относятся к категории с `id=1`. В итоге, если я укажу `id=1`, то должна отобразится категории с `id=2`, а если я укажу категорию с `id=2`, то должны отобразится категории с `id=1,3,4,5,6,9`.
Моя таблица: `id`, `name`, `parent_id`.

На скриншоте 2 наглядных примера. Если я укажу категорию с `id=38`, то категории с `id=41,42` не должны отображаться. С `id=7` похожая ситуация.
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понял вопрос, но может вам поможет (есть категория и есть его вложенные подкатегории и так далее). Чтобы достать все подкатегории и его id, то можете использовать такой код и переделать под себя:

```
public function getAllSubCategories(&$ids = [])
    {
        $subCategories = $this->subCategorys;

        foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
            $ids[] = $subCategory->id;
            $subCategory->getAllSubCategories($ids);
        }
        return $ids;
    }
```

Comment: Если что я это использовал в самой моделе и там где нужно вытащить все id которые пренадлежат основной категории я делал так 
$categ=Category::find(1);
$subcategId=$categ-> getAllSubCategories();